# By typescript, how to declare a member of specific ReactElement type in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to limit an interface member type for <Route ... /> only, the codes below seems not working.

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import { Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';

import Menu from 'feature/system/menu/Menu';

export interface IRouteConfig{
  readonly path: string,
  readonly name: string,
  readonly comp: ReactElement<RouteProps>,
}

const routes: IRouteConfig[] = [
    {path: "/feature/system/menu/correct", name: "correct menu", comp: <Route path="/feature/system/menu"><Menu /></Route>},
    {path: "/feature/system/menu/error", name: "error menu", comp: <Menu />},
];

export default routes;
```

what I excepted is a compiler error at second line in routes, but not any.
what's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX:

```
comp = <Route path="/feature/system/menu"><Menu /></Route>
```

equals to plain javascript

```
comp = Route({path:"/feature/system/menu", children: Menu()});
```

ie, running function `Route` with parameter `path` and `children`, and then assigning the function return value to comp.

So, by giving `comp` a type, you're really typing the **return value** of `Route`, typescript doesn't know what **parameter** you give to it, so it can't be typed!

PS: if you want to type a function's parameter, you need to declare it in function.

```
export const Menu = (props:RouteProps) => {
...
}
```

or

```
export function Menu(props:RouteProps) {
...
}
```